# Is a field of characteristic zero where -1 is a square algebraically closed?

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero where $-1$ is a square. Must $F$ be algebraically closed?

Comment: $F=\mathbb Q(i)$

Comment: @mrtaurho: Your comment perfectly answer the question. Why don't you post it as a solution. Also these and uncountably many fields with this property.

Comment: A related question is when adjoining $\sqrt{-1}$ to a field yields an algebraically closed one. This is the case precisely when the base field is real closed (or already algebraically closed in the trivial case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you give further assumption: no. Consider $F=\Bbb Q(i)$. This is a field extension of $\Bbb Q$ and thus of characteristic $0$ with $x^2=-1$ for $x=i$.